# Codeigniter customizing pagination links

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using CodeIgniter pagination,Consider 20 links pagination

Condition 1 : Show 5 links initially like below

```
1 2 3 4 5 next>>
```

Condition 2 : When 5th link is clicked, the number 5 should place two digits on either side like below

```
<<previous 3 4 5 6 7 next>>
```

I have change

```
$config["num_links"] = 2;
```

this works fine for condition 2 but initially it gives 3 links like below.

```
 1 2 3 next>>
```

When num_links changed to 4

```
$config["num_links"] = 4;
```

this works fine for condition 1 but fail to meet condition 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CodeIgniter` does not have any inbuilt configuration for this.

When you say: `$config["num_links"] = 2;` it just means add `2 previous` and `2 next` to the current page.

When you are in the first page, there is no previous and it adds two next so you get:

```
1 2 3 next>>
```

Same logic for the behavior when you do `$config["num_links"] = 4;`

If you really want to do it how you described you will have to extend the CI Pagination class with your own class:

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {...
```

And then add your custom pagination functions to it.

This [link](http://deniskomlev.com/blog/codeigniter-pagination-constant-links-number) looks like an interesting read and may help you.